# How can i know which virtual addresses/pages have been written at a certain point during a program's execution

Tags: linux, memory-management

I'm forking a child process from a main process. The physical addresses/pages are shared after forking but later some physical pages get duplicated due to copy-on-write scheme. I need to know the virtual addresses/pages which get duplicated due to COW. I know a mechanism - read the virtual address ranges from /proc/self/maps or smaps file and look for the page info in /proc/self/pagemap to get the PFN and the lookup the PFN in /proc/kpagecount to see the number of process references etc. But, that requires admin/root permissions.
Is there any other method that would not need root/admin access ?

I tried the method explained above but could not succeed as i do not have root/admin permissions unfortunately.

Comment: Please provide *reproducible* bash/terminal scripts that show exactly what is it you trying to achieve. Generally the to the only question you ask is no, however it doesn't seem to satisfy, please specify with test code what is it you want.